# How IBM JVM classloaders hold classes?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm, classloader

In HotSpot JVM `java.lang.Classloader` class has a Vector of all classes loaded by this classloader. And so all classes are held in memory as long as their's classloader is alive. In IBM JVM J9's java.lang.Classloader there is no such field. At least I was unable to find one. So my questions are:

1. Where does IBM JVM's classloaders hold class cache?
2. If differs from the point above: what hard-references classes in IBM JVM, thus preventing from unloading?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the code of my IBM JVM it seems that `java.lang.ClassLoader` is an abstract class, so it will be implemented somewhere. Using the debugger I found that is a synthetic class called `sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader`.
Then, to retrieve a class there is a native method
`private native Class findLoadedClassImpl(String className);` 

so it seems the caching is done outside Java, in a native method.

At the beginning of `loadClass` method I see:

```
// Ask the VM to look in its cache.
Class loadedClass = findLoadedClass(className);
```

then it checks whether `loadedClass` is null, and if so tries to use the parent clasloader.
So, I'd say that, unless the method is overridden by the inheriting classloader, caching happens outside Java, in some native component of IBM VM.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not solve my problem in no way :( And your answer is not IBM JVM specific as well. Hotspot behaves the same way, only it exposes class cache. J9 does not.

Comment: What is your problem? Do you need to read what is the class cache?

Comment: I had 2 problems in fact. One is easier to solve via workaround: to find what classes were loaded by this specific classloader. Second is a bit harder: to find out, who hard-references given classes thus preventing them from being GCed.

Comment: I think that's impossible with the default class loader, probably to make possible for he JVM to chare classes between different JVM processes http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/java7sdk/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.java.lnx.70.doc/diag/understanding/shared_classes.html (as a wild guess, I think it's used in application servers to mitigate permgen size issues), so in general you shouldn't be able to access this cache, since to implement your own caching mechanism you can implement your own classloader.

Comment: Well, first part can be achieved using java.lang.instrument.Instrumentation, so this is quite possible.

Comment: How? You will intercept calls to findLoadedClassImpl, but will not read directly inside the cache, isn't it? What's the goal?

Comment: I will call instrumentation.getInitiatedClasses(classLoader) .

Answer (score 1):

The IBM J9 JVM has no PermGen on Heap and stores Classes in native memory. You can use -Xdump to generate a javacore.* file, it will contain a list of all classloaders and classes.

BTW: Java8 will do a similiar thing.